# Istanbul for protractor code coverage

Tags: angularjs, tdd, code-coverage, protractor, istanbul

Does Istanbul provide code coverage for protractor tests? If yes, does is show passed and failed test details? I want to generate an HTML report of tests failed or passed using Istanbul. Is that even possible?

Comment: There is a link to sample HTML reports with passed/failed tests right in their homepage so I'm not exactly sure what's the point of your question. Have you tried generating a report and have had a problem with it? If yes you should provide more details in order for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, check this plugin out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-coverage.
All you need is to run your tests against instrumented code, that will store coverage in some global variable.

So:
1. instrument your code manually with istanbul
2. run tests against it
3. export global.variable content in some file
4. make instanbul report on this file